# Loading applet in browser throws Classnotfound exception

Tags: java, plugins, applet, browser-plugin

When i tried to run applet in my firefox browser, it was prompted to install java plugin. I have downloaded and installed the plugin **Java 7 Update 17**.

Later, i tried to load applet again, but im getting the error. I get this in all the browsers. My friends can load this applet though. Please help me resolve this. Thanks

Java Plug-in 10.17.2.02
Using JRE version 1.7.0_17-b02 Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM

### User home directory = C:\Users\Administrator

c:   clear console window
f:   finalize objects on finalization queue
g:   garbage collect
h:   display this help message
l:   dump classloader list
m:   print memory usage
o:   trigger logging
q:   hide console
r:   reload policy configuration
s:   dump system and deployment properties
t:   dump thread list
v:   dump thread stack
x:   clear classloader cache

### 0-5: set trace level to

```
cache: Initialize resource manager: com.sun.deploy.cache.ResourceProviderImpl@17825dd
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.
security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp
security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.access value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.access new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss,com.sun.browser,com.sun.glass,com.sun.javafx,com.sun.media.jfxmedia,com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl,com.sun.openpisces,com.sun.prism,com.sun.scenario,com.sun.t2k,com.sun.webpane,com.sun.pisces,com.sun.webkit
security: property package.definition value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss
security: property package.definition new value sun.,com.sun.xml.internal.bind.,com.sun.xml.internal.org.jvnet.staxex.,com.sun.xml.internal.ws.,com.sun.imageio.,com.sun.istack.internal.,com.sun.jmx.,com.sun.proxy.,com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.utils.,com.sun.org.glassfish.external.,com.sun.org.glassfish.gmbal.,com.sun.javaws,com.sun.deploy,com.sun.jnlp,org.mozilla.jss,com.sun.browser,com.sun.glass,com.sun.javafx,com.sun.media.jfxmedia,com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl,com.sun.openpisces,com.sun.prism,com.sun.scenario,com.sun.t2k,com.sun.webpane,com.sun.pisces,com.sun.webkit
basic: Added progress listener: sun.plugin.util.ProgressMonitorAdapter@15b3296
basic: Plugin2ClassLoader.addURL parent called for http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://10.10.10.129:8080/ with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar with cookie "expandable=5c; subexpandable=18c"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.downloadJAR(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin.PluginURLJarFileCallBack.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.retrieve(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.URLJarFile.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarFileFactory.get(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFileInternal(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin.net.protocol.jar.CachedJarURLConnection.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.getJarFile(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.access$1000(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$JarLoader.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getLoader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.deploy.security.DeployURLClassPath.getResource(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader$2.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.findClassHelper(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
    at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar, version: null]
network: Connecting http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar with proxy=DIRECT
network: Connecting http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar with cookie "expandable=5c; subexpandable=18c"
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem started here:

```
network: Cache entry not found [url: http://10.10.10.129:8080/Sistic/resources/lib/Printer-1.0-executable.jar, version: null]
```

Please make sure the fetched jar file is at the specified directory.

Comment: Actually the jar file resides in the directory. It is running in all other machines except mine